# Tricky Star Wars problem...

Tags: calculus

I've got a tricky problem, at least I think...

"A brave X-Wing pilot flies to the left along the graph of f(x)=x/(x-1). At the point (0,1) there is an exhaust pipe that the pilot is going to hit with a laser shot. When the pilot shoots the shot will travel along the tangent line of the curve."

**a) Draw a picture of the situation.**

We know that x=1 is a horizontal asymptote. I took the limits of f(x) as x->∞ and x->1 to see what happened graphically. Then I took the same limits of f'(x). So I've got this part.

**b) Find the slope of f(x) at a point x=a where a>0 by using the derivative definition.**

What I did:

f'(a) = lim h->0 ((a+h)/(a+h-1)-a/(a-1))/h = -1/(a-1)^2 (after factoring etc.)

**c) Find the tangent line for f(x) at the point x=a above.**

Is this just the derivative?

**d) For what value of x=a should the pilot shoot to hit the exhaust pipe?**

I suppose I should make use of the fact that the tangent line must equal the function value at some point, since the shot travels along the tangent line but I'm not sure.

**e) Within which interval does the pilot have to shoot if the exhaust pipe has a width ε? Here it is enough to give an interval that works. (Although, the wider the interval, the easier you're making it for the pilot)**

Comment: May the (differentiable) force be with you.

Comment: You haven't upvoted or accepted a single question. You go first.

Answer (score 0):

When drawing the picture of the situation, don't forget the exhaust port!

To find the tangent line for $f(x)$ at $x=a,$ you will certainly need the derivative of $f$ at $x=a,$ as it is the slope of that tangent line. However, you also need a point on the line to find the equation for the tangent line (which isn't difficult to find).

Once you've found the general equation for that tangent line (which should depend on $a$), you'll want to make sure that the "laser" passes through the "exhaust port" at $(0,1)$--that is, you'll want to make sure that $(0,1)$ is a point on the tangent line.

As for part (e), if the exhaust port has width $\varepsilon,$ then you must determine for which $a$ the tangent line passes through a point $(0,y_0),$ where $$1-\frac\varepsilon2<y_0<1+\frac\varepsilon2.$$ Note that this is based on my interpretation of the problem. It may be that your instructor intends the inequality to be non-strict, which you should check.